# wxpython, showing modal dialog one by one

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have multi threaded wxpython app and main GUI thread receives notification from other threads to show it under modal dialog box. I want some kind of scheduling/queuing so dialog should appear one after other if multiple notification (from other threads) comes at same time.

Comment: Multiple modal windows sounds like an awful idea for the user. They will all take focus away from the application. Are you sure you don't want notification window instead?

Comment: Idea is, one notification (either as modal windows or simple notification) at a time. Few notification requires user interaction hence modal window looks suitable here.

Comment: A modal window would be NOT suitable for this very reason. They require user interaction and prevent your app from processing input until it is dismissed. What you want is a MODELESS dialog box. Maybe look into: `wx.notificationmessage`

Comment: The main issue is how to show notification one by one. Notification could be modal windows, modal less windows, balloon tip and it hardly matter in my case.

Answer (score 1):

As each notification arrives add it to a queue, (i.e. a list), and as each dialog is closed remove that notification from the queue and if it is not empty show the next - *and listen to your users complain*.

**N.B.** Be especially careful not to get into a situation I spotted a few times where clicking on the dismiss button always caused another notification. Another classic case was an error window reporting too many error windows were open.

Comment: Good idea to use queue here. The question is, how can I read/listen queue in main GUI loop? I do not want to use another thread for that.

Comment: Have an event handler for your thread that adds to the queue and checks a flag for if there is currently a dialogue visible, if there isn't then set it, pop the top off the queue & show the dialogue. In the dismiss handler for the notification dialogue(s) recheck the queue and if it is empty clear the flag otherwise pop the top request off the queue and show it.